# which concept is use? i am new on developing android app

Tags: android

I want to develop an application like social network app.
In that app if one user that use my application is post an image or some text.. that text or image can see other user that also use my application.
I want to know that how that can be possible?
using which concept or library or whatever?
I am totally blank about this question..

Thanks in advance.
waiting for reply.

Comment: Rule # 1 : Google is your very good friend. Search for a tutorial & study your self. When you stuck in a code problem come here with code & error logs. :)  **This is the best concept here.**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into the Observer pattern.

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems. The Observer pattern is also a key part in the familiar model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern.[1] The observer pattern is implemented in numerous programming libraries and systems,